# Mysql: migrating 4.0 duplicate primary key issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a large database from 4.0 to 5.7, and one table is generating a lot of errors for duplicate primary keys.

Table schema:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| word_text   | varchar(50) binary    |      | PRI |         |                |
| word_id     | mediumint(8) unsigned |      | MUL | NULL    | auto_increment |
| word_common | tinyint(1) unsigned   |      |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The error happens on rows that have unicode chars in it, so that "spam" and "spam∫y" exist but are considered duplicates, as if the unicode char is stopping the comparison algorithm.

How can I get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should change the collation of your column to something that allows accented characters.

Comment: Are you doing import from an *.sql dump file? Or are you using an app like SQLyog to copy the database?

Comment: I'm using a dump file from the earlier version. It appears that 4.x can make the differentiation between the two keys.